# Mysql less code when columns names share the same prefix

Tags: php

When I have a table in database where some columns names have similar prefix plus incremental index 'var_1,var_2...', to make less code, Usually I use this thing :

```
for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++)
  {
      if($i < 9)
      $query .= 'prefix_'.$i.'=:value_'.$i.' AND ';
      else
      $query .= 'prefix_'.$i.'=:value_'.$i;

  }
$final_query = "UPDATE  $table SET  ".$query;

$stmt = $conn->prepare($final_query );
    
for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++)
  {
      $stmt->bindValue(':value_'.$i, $values[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  }
```

Is it ok to do like this or there is something different to do for less code?

Comment: Usually columns like this are poor database design. You should have another table where each value is in a separate row, with a foreign key pointing back to the main table.

Comment: That said, if you're stuck with this table design, this is a fine way to do it.

Comment: @Barmar, Just think on album table with columns 'link_img_1,link_img_2,...' is it a bad design ?

Comment: YES, IT IS!!!!!!

Comment: Yes, what if you want more than 10 images?

Comment: Generally, yes, it is. However, there may be some application specific business cases that require such design - this is something you need to judge. But this wuestion is very broad and the code is more about php than mysql.

Comment: And don't forget about Bobby Tables, even with PDO. This is so wrong in so many levels I can't even begin to enumerate them. Anyway there are a lot of PHP (I assume) ORM that do this, instead of creating a new one from scratch.

Comment: I have set a maximum limit for the number of images per album, by the way is for classified ads.

Comment: See the difference of storing data in a single row vs multiple rows; and how is the data insertion process for both in this simple example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b04fef8affb8e1505475ecdd76be89f9

Comment: @FanoFN thank you for the link !

Comment: Storing data in multiple rows reduce the number of column significantly , and it's easy to find information , for example in case of single row You should iterate over the whole table to find images of a given album id !

Comment: @CoDevloop it seems that you've figured out a solution? Can you post as answer and accept as your own solution so others who might face the same issue can consider to use your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this for your $query

```
$query = implode(' AND ', 
    array_map(fn($i) => 'prefix_'.$i.'=:value_'.$i, range(0,9)));
```

maps the numbers 0..9 into an array, then joins them all using ' AND ' as a separator

Comment: What if I want to skip some indexes?

Comment: in that case you'd need to have an array of the indices you WANT, and use that instead of `range(0,9)`, or have an array of ones you don't want and use `array_diff`

Comment: making code shorter is often a fools errand. It usually doesn't make it faster or more readable. But, getting rid of repeated code can be helpful. I do think using `implode` is helpful for readability and less prone to errors than making a special case for the last entry

Comment: I appreciate your helpful answer.